# Jacoco reports path not found by sonar-runner

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, sonar-runner

I generated a coverage report using [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/index.html) with the following path :

```
C:/tmp/coverageReport/report.exec
```

This file exists, is not empty and is readable.
My sonnar-runner configuration regarding code coverage is defined as follows :

```
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.junit.reportsPath=C:/tmp/coverageReport/report.exec
```

The analysis completes successfully but no data is visible in the *Unit test coverage* widget.

Moreover, I get the following lines during the analysis :

```
18:23:45.036 INFO  - parsing C:/tmp/coverageReport/report.exec
18:23:45.037 WARN  - Reports path not found: C:/tmp/coverageReport/report.exec
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 11):

There is a big difference between sonar.junit.reportPath and sonar.jacoco.reportPath. You are mixing up the values.

Similarly, there's sonar.jacoco.itReportPath (for non-Unit tests based jaocco.exec files for ex: jacocoIT.exec (if you are creating for Integration tests).

Now, Depending upon the version of sonarQube instance (4.x or latest 5.x.x), you may need to set either sonar.junit.reportPath or sonar.java.junit.reportPath to the value (which is the folder containing the .xml data).

**For ex**: If my Unit tests or Integration tests folder's result files (.xmls) are in folder build/test-results/UT folder, then:

```
sonar.java.junit.reportPath=build/test-results/UT
```

or

```
sonar.junit.reportPath=build/test-results/UT
```

For the code coverage file (.exec), you have to use:

```
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec
```

or

```
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec
```

**Important** - Sonar Properties:

sonar.**jacoco**.xxx *points to the filename*.

sonar.**junit**.xxx    *or* sonar.**java.junit**.xxx *points to a folder name*.

sonar.**surefire**.xxx *or* sonar.**java.surefire**.xxx *points to a folder name*.

Similar to **sonar.junit.reportPath**, there's also another property called: sonar.**surefire**.reportPath or sonar.**java.surefire**.reportPath. Look for Sonar docs for more help under Analyzing Source code with Maven/Gradle.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+Source+Code (expand it).

For ex: Under [Analyze with Gradle build system](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/gradle.html), look for **Configure Analysis Properties** section/more.

Comment: unfortunately, this is deprecated, you can see here for the update: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/